# Transferring specific information within a group in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I got results after a duplicate check for company name like this:

```
|customernumber|duplicate group |companyname|street   |telephone| 
|1             |1               |ABC group  |Alpha 112|017887   |
|3             |1               |ABC group  |Alpha    |017887   |
|4             |2               |DEF group  |Beta  223|034887   |
|7             |2               |DEF group  |Beta  112|017555   |
|9             |3               |GHI group  |Gamma 007|016386   |
|19            |3               |GHI group  |Gamma 007|         |
|5             |4               |JKL group  |DELTA 007|026386   |
|6             |4               |JKL group  |DELTA    |         |
```

And I want this result:

```
|customernumber|duplicate group |companyname|street   |telephone| 
|1             |1               |ABC group  |Alpha 112|017887   |
|3             |1               |ABC group  |Alpha 112|017887   |
|4             |2               |DEF group  |Beta  223|034887   |
|7             |2               |DEF group  |Beta  112|017555   |
|9             |3               |GHI group  |Gamma 007|016386   |
|19            |3               |GHI group  |Gamma 007|016386   |
|5             |4               |JKL group  |DELTA 007|026386   |
|6             |4               |JKL group  |DELTA 007|026386   |
```

Rules:

1. Add (only) the House number when there is one entry with an house number in the same duplicate group to the entry without a house number (duplicate group 1)
2. Add the phone number when there is one entry with a phone number in the same duplicate group to the entry without a phone number (duplicate group 2)
3. Add (only) the House number AND the phone number when there is one entry with a House number AND phone number in the same duplicate group to the entry without a House number AND phone number (duplicate group 3)

SPECIFIC:

Sometimes there are more than 2 entries inside a duplicate group -> e.g. sometimes 2 have a (different) house number and 1 not or so... (When there are different house numbers or/telephone numbers it doesn't matter which one is chosen to be added)

I have no idea how to solve it; I only found that to that to test, if there is a number inside a string:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE Column LIKE '%[0-9]%'
```

I am grateful for any help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This has the look of a Homework question; generally students should be answering these questions themselves. To start with, what is your actual question here? It seems you forgot to ask one when you posted your question. The only thing you have to show you have tried so far is a `SELECT` with a `WHERE` (however reference the column `column`, which doesn't exist in your data). Please udpate your post to include your question, make sure it's specific([mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) and show what you have actually tried. Thank you.

Comment: These are my requirements (Questions)- no homework questions. The result is the result I want to receive. The "select where statement" is just a first step - and I don´t now the second one...

Comment: maybe I can use an innerjoin on duplicate number...

Comment: Requirements aren't questions. Stack overflow isn't a free coding service, it's a Q&A website. The volunteers here will be happy to help you answer any questions you might have, but they aren't here to do your work for you (you should be hiring, and paying, people for that). Have a look at the [Asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) page, which explains how and what you can ask about. Update your post to show what specific part you're having trouble with, and a specific question and the volunteers, including myself, will be happy to help you get across the line.#

Comment: Which is the version of SQL Server you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any of the following queries depending on your SQL Server version. The idea is to use `MAX` over strings to get the `more completed` (more long) one as every symbol is larger then empty string when strings are compared.

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [customernumber] INT
   ,[duplicate group] INT
   ,[companyname] VARCHAR(128)
   ,[street] VARCHAR(256)
   ,[telephone] VARCHAR(32)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([customernumber], [duplicate group], [companyname], [street], [telephone])
VALUES (1, 1, 'ABC group', 'Alpha 112', '017887')
      ,(3, 1, 'ABC group', 'Alpha', '017887')
      ,(4, 2, 'DEF group', 'Beta  223', '034887')
      ,(7, 2, 'DEF group', 'Beta  112', '017555')
      ,(9, 3, 'GHI group', 'Gamma 007', '016386')
      ,(19, 3, 'GHI group', 'Gamma 007', '')
      ,(5, 4, 'JKL group', 'DELTA 007', '026386')
      ,(6, 4, 'JKL group', 'DELTA', '');


WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT [duplicate group]
          ,MAX([street]) AS [street]
          ,MAX([telephone]) AS [telephone]
    FROM @DataSource
    GROUP BY [duplicate group]
)
SELECT DS.[customernumber]
      ,DS.[duplicate group]
      ,DS.[companyname]
      ,CASE WHEN DS.[street] NOT LIKE '%[0-9]%' THEN CTE.[street] ELSE DS.[street] END AS [street]
      ,CASE WHEN DS.[telephone] = '' THEN CTE.[telephone] ELSE DS.[telephone] END AS [telephone]
FROM @DataSource DS
INNER JOIN DataSource CTE
    ON DS.[duplicate group] = CTE.[duplicate group];

SELECT [customernumber]
      ,[duplicate group]
      ,[companyname]
      ,IIF([street] NOT LIKE '%[0-9]%', MAX([street]) OVER(PARTITION BY [duplicate group]), [street]) AS [street]
      ,IIF([telephone] = '', MAX([telephone]) OVER(PARTITION BY [duplicate group]), [telephone]) AS [telephone]
FROM @DataSource;
```

[image]